# How to get Dictionary Key at index 0 in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary

I have dictionary object like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictInputColumnNames;
...
```

I want to get the key at index 0 in this dictionary, I have the same code in vb which is like this:

```
Dim inputFieldName As String = dictInputColumnNames(dictInputColumnNames.Keys(0))
```

What is the equivalent code in C#

Answer (score -1):

Use [`ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat) to get the key:

```
int myKey = dictInputColumnNames.Keys.ElementAt(0);
```

You can then use the key to retrieve the value:

```
string inputFieldName = dictInputColumnNames[myKey];
```